# How to pick one of the results of UNIQUE() in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, unique, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

**Problem**

I have a column with duplicate items in Google Sheets, and I would like to get one of the unique values (say, the last one) in the cell of the formula. Is there a way to do this with just formulas (i.e., no scripts/macros)?

**What I've tried**

Not sure if this is the best way, but I've tried using the `UNIQUE(range)` function, which returns a list of distinct values, and I tried to pick one with `FILTER(range, condition1, [condition2, …])`, but I've only managed to do it when I know in advance and hard-code in the number of unique values.

[image]

Since I can get the length of the unique list with `=LEN(UNIQUE(my_range))`, I tried using the `REPT(text_to_repeat, number_of_repetitions)` function.

For example,

`=REPT(0&";",2) & 1` returns "0;0;1"

but

`=FILTER(UNIQUE(A$1:A$26), {REPT(0&";",2) & 1})`

(or any variation I tried) doesn't quite work.

[image]

**P.S.**
I realise this is not the most suitable problem for a spreadsheet, and I do wish I was using something like Python, but this is the restriction at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or more old-school using index:

```
=index(unique(A:A),counta(unique(A:A)))
```

[image]

You can also just enter a number fot the one you want e.g.

```
=index(unique(A:A),2)
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE(A1:A), "offset "&COUNTA(UNIQUE(A1:A))-1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This works and is fascinating because I had no idea about the Query function, which definitely makes life easier, so +1! However, I marked Tom Sharpe's answer as the accepted one just because it's (slightly) simpler and still answers the specific question.